# X does not load after debian upgrade

Tags: debian, xorg, x11

After upgrading to "jessie" (debian 8) from stable (debian 7), the system hangs at a blank screen (displaying only an underscore at the top left corner), but otherwise displays no error message to support a diagnosis. The problem seems to be a failure to load `X`, and the following warnings are contained in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[     8.810] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     8.834] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     8.834] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[445797.803] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (Connection refused)
[445800.781] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (Connection refused)
[526625.329] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (Connection refused)
[527190.989] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (Connection refused)
```

I have tried investigating the error messages relating to `vesa`, `fbdev`, and `Open ACPI`, but haven't found anything particularly helpful. The lack of cyrillic font does not seem very important and ACPI relates to power settings, so I suspect a solution might involve fixing the `vesa` and `fbdev` errors. I'm wondering if these messages mean something to anyone, and if so, if a remedy might be suggested.

**Edit 1:**

Some system information that may be pertinent:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

uname -a
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit 2:**

I was checking an outdated log file (`Xorg.0.log`). Searching for errors and warnings in the most recently updated log file (`Xorg.1.log`) reveals the following:

```
[   232.705] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   232.717] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   232.717] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   232.718] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
```

Comment: which graphic card do you have?

Comment: The timestamps look strange. Have you rebooted?

Comment: @pqnet: Sorry to not have added enough pertinent information. I have updated the question accordingly. I notice that `uname -a` shows `deb7u3`, whereas "jessie" (debian testing) is deb8. Perhaps the upgrade did not go to completion?

Comment: @vinc17: I rebooted several times after upgrade, but I'm not quite sure how to interpret the timestamp. I was thinking they might be in ms post-reboot, but no units are provided.

Comment: are you able to switch to a terminal pressing alt+f1 when the error occurs?

Comment: I'd probably post the whole log somewhere. If it is too long, you could add a link. Also, what is the relevant portion of the x config? Are you using the `intel` driver? And any third party modules you forgot to upgrade?

Comment: Try switching to another VT after booting (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), logging in and running `startx 2>&1 > startx.log` and see what turns up in startx.log.

Comment: 445797.803 means several days after reboot. So, I don't understand how this is possible. Are you sure that the `Xorg.0.log` file is the right one?

Comment: Can you provide all the latest lines of the `Xorg.0.log`? `tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: @pqnet: Pressing ctrl+alt+F1 at the frozen screen permits display of the few boot messages that normally occur and then disappear and also shows additional lines `Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid [hostname] tty1`. Just below this line is a prompt (`[hostname] login:`) allowing me to login. Thus, the problem does seem to be `X`-related.

Comment: Also look at the log messages of your display manager.

Comment: @arnefm: After doing this, the following line appears in `startx.log`: `/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1`. Note that I did this on VT `ctrl+alt+F1` rather than `ctrl+alt+F2`, as in my response to pqnet (though I don't think that this matters).

Comment: `display :1` means that the correct X log file should be `Xorg.1.log`, not `Xorg.0.log` (which seems to be too old due to its timestamps).

Comment: @vinc17: Good points. I had just confirmed this by `ls -lrt /log/var/Xorg*`, which shows log 1 to be the valid file. After searching for warnings and errors in this log file (`egrep "WW|EE"`), additional warnings were found (added these as an "edit" to the question).

Comment: I have the same warnings. This is not related to the problem.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I am using the Intel driver. I don't believe I forgot to upload any third party modules. I'll upload the whole `Xorg.1.log` in a paste bin. Could you please tell me what you mean by the relevant portion of the x config? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any msgs in `/var/log/syslog`? Also take a look at this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=825072#p825072

Comment: @slm: There are 54,000 messages printed to `/var/log/syslog`, all from today. Thanks for the link. My `xorg.conf` file is completely empty, so perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: @user001 - You'll have to comb through those msgs to see what's up, unfortunately 8-(.

Comment: @user001 The part of the X config concerned with the video driver is what I meant, but you could also paste the whole thing if you want. To be clear, this is usually `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Here are the Xorg log files modified today: http://pastebin.com/y48ZG9zH

Comment: @Braiam: Added the full Xorg log files at the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, it seems that everything is fine: no errors. But the X display may be on tty8 instead of tty7. So, switch to tty8 with Ctrl-Alt-F8.

EDIT: This is a known problem: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29920

Example of bug where the screen is black while `startx` works (this may be related or give some ideas): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744152

Comment: Thanks. I find that `tty1` is command-line only; `tty2` is graphical (it's what displays `X` after running `startx` via `tty1`); `tty3`--`tty6` all display a login prompt; `tty7` displays a static underscore in the top left corner (which is the same thing I observe when the system hangs on boot); and `tty8` displays a blinking underscore in the same position.

Comment: @user001 I suppose that `Xorg.1.log` corresponds to the server started with `startx`. I suspect a bug (or misconfiguration) of your display manager. For instance, your display manager may crash before it starts a X server, as `startx` shows that there are no problems with X.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking over the bug report you sent now and trying to see if I can figure out why the display manager is not running on boot.

Comment: @user001 Use bootlogd to get `/var/log/boot` messages (you should see one or a few lines related to your display manager). If everything is fine here, then you should see where your display manager has sent log messages.

Comment: During installation, the installer asked me whether I should keep (default action) or replace two existing config files that differed from incoming files. One of the files was `/etc/init.d/bootlogd`. I opted to retain both of the existing config files (the default action), but since then, nothing is written to /var/log/boot, so I think I should have taken the new config file.

Comment: @user001 Concerning your bootlogd problem, it could be the following bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=716948

Comment: I ended up formatting my drive and performing a fresh installation. Evidently, the Debian upgrade process is quite fragile.

Comment: @user001 YOu are not required to accept an answer if it doesn't fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your `acpid` daemon isn't running, for some unknown reason. You can confirm this if you're able to get shell access to the system like so:

```
$ pgrep -l acpi
```

You should get some response back. If you do you can double check how `acpid` is being invoked with this command:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep acpi
```

If it isn't running you might want to try forcing it during your system's boot by appending the following to your GRUB line for the kernel. You can do this during the initial boot by appending this:

```
$ apci=force
```

These options are discussed further in this article titled: [BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) from the Ubuntu community wiki.

Comment: Thanks @slm. Seems I was checking the wrong `Xorg` log file, and the correct log file actually does not contain any `acpi` warnings (see "Edit 2") in the question. I did try what you suggested and found `ktpacpid` and ``ktpacpi_nvramd`` as active `root`-owned processes.